# Is it kosher to ask for books suggestions?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask for books suggestions based on some specific characteristic (like being "similar to book A, but with more/less X"?).

I.e. "I'd like to read something similar to Harry Potter but with more adult themes, what would you suggest"? or "I am looking for novels close to DC's John Constantine in tone".

If this is allowed, how should this be tagged?

Comment: "I'd like to read something similar to Harry Potter but with more adult themes" - I heard that there's this site with words fan fiction in the URL... Never seen one. Pinky swear.

Answer (score 8):

It is not allowed. There were problems with recommendations from early on, and they were banned. We suggest you become familiar with the chat room, the guys in there can often help you well.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks...

Comment: If he wants Harry Potter with adult themes recommendations, it's not the **guys** in the chat room he needs to ask :))))   [ Hint: someone with Royal blood ]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not kosher.

For something to be [kosher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher_foods), it must be prepared according to stringent requirements, including being overseen by a Jewish Rabbi.

Of course, these questions aren't eaten, so that would be difficult in any case.

(And, of course, Pearson has already given and answer to the text of the question, though he completely ignored the question in the title.)